# Gradient text in a UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, cagradientlayer

I'm using a CAGradientLayer to make a gradient background for a text field. It looks like this

[image]

Instead of the background I want to have the gradient on the text. How can I make gradient text in a UITextField?

The code I used to make the gradient in the image

```
pinkDarkOp = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9f green:0.53f blue:0.69f alpha:1.0];
pinkLightOp = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.79f green:0.45f blue:0.57f alpha:1.0];

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = [[myTextField layer] bounds];
gradient.cornerRadius = 7;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      (id)pinkDarkOp.CGColor,
                      (id)pinkLightOp.CGColor,
                      nil];
[[myTextField layer]addSublayer:gradient];
```

Comment: usually in stack over flow i don't have answer i don't know why?

Comment: One possible reason for why you didn't get any answers was that the question was fairly hard to understand. I tried to make it more clear. From the original question I assume that you want to make gradient text (instead of the black color in that image).

Comment: no i want to apply gradient pink color to my textfield but the gradient cover all the frame not only the text

Comment: But isn't the gradient currently covering the entire frame? (See even after reading your question multiple times I didn't understand what you were asking)

Comment: simply i want gradient color only for the text not the entire frame of the textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by creating two layers:
First you create a layer which you fill with the gradient.
Then you create another layer containing the text.
Finally you use the second layer as a mask for masking the first layer. This is achieved by assigning the second layer to the mask property of the first layer.

If I look more specifically on your code example, I think that everything before the last line should be OK. But then you should replace the last line with something like this:

```
gradient.mask = myTextField.layer;
```

Perhaps you need to do some adjustments to `myTextField` as well (hard to say since its definition is not part of the listed code). It's important to understand that the text in the mask must be opaque but the rest of that layer must be fully transparent. Read about the "mask" property in the CALayer class reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/mask

Dislaimer: I have not had time to test the code. I leave that to you. But the general idea of masking one layer with another should be possible to use, so I am convinced that you can sort out the details by yourself.

Comment: think you i will test this solution now

Comment: i added a new calayer for the text  CALayer *textLayer2 = (CALayer *)[myTextField.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0];
and i added it as a mask of the cagradient layer gradient.mask=textLayer2; but no results

Comment: UITextField is not the easiest class to work with when trying to modify the visual appearance by tweaking the layers. I encourage you to start experimenting with a simpler class, e.g. a UILabel, until you know that you fully understand how masking is working. When you get the masking right with that class, you can then switch back to UITextField again and continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

i made somme changes in my codes

```
pinkDarkOp = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9f green:0.53f blue:0.69f alpha:1.0];
           pinkLightOp = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.79f green:0.45f blue:0.57f alpha:1.0];
        gradient.frame = [[myTextField layer] bounds];
        gradient.cornerRadius = 7;
       gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)pinkDarkOp.CGColor,
                                             (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], nil]; 
           gradient.mask=myTextField.layer;
```

the text is invisible now
[image]